# Encode error in python

Tags: python, twitter, utf-8, ascii

I was trying to parse twitter data. I retrieved the data and stored it in a file named 
'**twitterdata**'

```
f = open('twitterdata','r')
for line in f:
    jsonline = json.loads(line)
    for key in jsonline:
        print str(jsonline[key]).encode('utf-8')
```

I am getting the error even after using **encode('utf-8')**:

```
print str(jsonline[key]).encode('utf-8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-17: ordinal not in     range(128)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using, 2.x or 3.x? Unicode handling changed between the two versions, so it's important to know which version you're using so we can give you the correct answer.

Comment: I am using python 2.7.3. Using pycharm IDE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the `str()`, or change it to `unicode()`:

```
print jsonline[key].encode('utf-8')
```

or

```
print unicode(jsonline[key]).encode('utf-8')
```

In Python 2.x, `str()` tries to convert its contents to 8-bit strings. Since you're passing it Unicode objects, it uses the default encoding (`ascii`) and fails, before the `.encode('utf-8')` call is reached. Using `unicode()` is redundant here if the data you're getting is all text, but will be useful if some of it is, say, integers, so I recommend the latter.